# how can I fetch a website and overwrite some ot its html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a website, which would fetch someone's website and display it with my CSS. It would also delete few html tags, how can I do this?? Any tips, what to search internet for??

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: You can use a frame and then inject your css into the frame.

Comment: Sounds like a serverside [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about it using `<iframes>`. They let you do a lot in terms of changing existing things on websites.

You would use something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

to display the site, then you can inspect element to get their `.class` and `.id` names to change out colors with normal `CSS`

Some websites use protection so they cannot be viewed in an `iframe`, Google is one of them, for future reference, if you run into this issue, **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)** explains why.